# Change expandable indicator in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

Trying to create an ExpandableListView. The initial view with the groups shows up fine. However, when I click the list item, my arrow does not change. See the images below.

[image]

How can I change the arrow's direction?

The layout XML:

```
  <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
```

**settings_selector.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down"
        android:state_empty="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:state_expanded="true"/>
</selector>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Post the listView row xml

Comment: @RajeshCP see update one

Comment: Onclick of the onItemClick function you can change the source of the group_indicator for that you need a uparrow button or else you can rotate the bitmap by some dregree and set it as a source for that ImageView

Comment: @RajeshCP in left side arrow working nice use this http://www.hrupin.com/2012/08/how-to-create-custom-groupindicator-for-expandablelistview-group one but how to solve right side arrow

Comment: Edit your lay out accordingly for that

Comment: for which one i want how to change that left side button to right side @RajeshCP

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26510/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-rajesh-cp)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

expandable listview

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />
```

`setindicator` here iam useing setindicator code like this this working nice

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels; 

 mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
 mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));  

   public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
    // Get the screen's density scale 
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

res/drawable/group_indicator

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">            
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" android:state_empty="true">  </item>            
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true"></item>                
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"></item>
     </selector>
```

Comment: `mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - 50, width - 10);` gives Same output.. Why?????

Comment: use expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative in android 4.3

Comment: You can save indicator size in dimens.xml:
<dimen name="indicator_bounds">-50dp</dimen>
And then use built in method to calculate dp to pixels:
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.indicator_bounds)

Comment: icon is streched to the height of the layout

Answer (score 26):

Try that for your `settings_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:state_expanded="true" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" />

</selector>
```

Comment: You didn't post your answer when I posted mine :)

Comment: becouse it is is usefull to any new developers.

Answer (score 17):

I had gone the way below: decide the left/right drawable for your groupView based on isExpanded flag.
By that way, it is easier for us to customize the padding/background and other things of the indicator drawable.

Hope it helps.

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_group, null);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, isExpanded ? 0 : android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more, 0);
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        mExpandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        ArrayList<Parent> arrayParents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();

        //here we set the parents and the children
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            //for each "i" create a new Parent object to set the title and the children
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            parent.setTitle("Parent " + i);

            arrayChildren = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                arrayChildren.add("Child " + j);
            }
            parent.setArrayChildren(arrayChildren);

            //in this array we add the Parent object. We will use the arrayParents at the setAdapter
            arrayParents.add(parent);
        }

        //sets the adapter that provides data to the list.
        mExpandableList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(MyActivity.this,arrayParents));

    }

    public class Parent {
        private String mTitle;
        private ArrayList<String> mArrayChildren;

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
            this.mTitle = mTitle;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getArrayChildren() {
            return mArrayChildren;
        }

        public void setArrayChildren(ArrayList<String> mArrayChildren) {
            this.mArrayChildren = mArrayChildren;
        }
    }




    public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements OnClickListener{


        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<Parent> mParent;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parent){
            mParent = parent;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }


        @Override
        //counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many times calls getGroupView() method
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return mParent.size();
        }

        @Override
        //counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times calls getChildView() method
        public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
            return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().size();
        }

        @Override
        //gets the title of each parent/group
        public Object getGroup(int i) {
            return mParent.get(i).getTitle();
        }

        @Override
        //gets the name of each item
        public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
            return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
            return i1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        //in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list
        public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_parent, viewGroup,false);
            }
            view.findViewById(R.id.button).setTag(i);
            view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
            //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list
            textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());

            //return the entire view
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        //in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list
        public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, viewGroup,false);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_child);
            //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list and
            //"i1" is the position of the child
            textView.setText(mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1));

            //return the entire view
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
            /* used to make the notifyDataSetChanged() method work */
            super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        }


        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
         * @since Mar 20, 2013
         * @author rajeshcp 
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mExpandableList.isGroupExpanded((Integer)v.getTag()))
        {
            mExpandableList.collapseGroup((Integer)v.getTag());
        }else
        {
            mExpandableList.expandGroup((Integer)v.getTag());
        }
        }
    }


}
```

Change your `MyActivity` like this and let me know what else you want ?

Comment: in this no `onitemclick`  in expandablelistview necessary to use an `onitemclick`.

Comment: I really don understand what you want ?

Comment: see http://www.hrupin.com/2012/08/how-to-create-custom-groupindicator-for-expandablelistview-group this example in place of left side image how change that image to right side.

Comment: I'am useing that example only that image how to change like left to right side same as my image like in question have one image like that..

Comment: hey see the edited answer after running the application just click on each buttons in the row

Comment: Any way thanks my issue solved we see my answer working nice.

Answer (score 4):

subject:

```
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        listView.setIndicatorBounds(width - getPixelValue(40), width - getPixelValue(10));
    } else {
        listView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - getPixelValue(40), width - getPixelValue(10));
    }
```

and helper method:

```
public static int getPixelValue(int dp) {

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party but my requirement was something similar to this but something was different.

[image]

I had 3 requirements:

1. if a group have child then show down_arrow (V)
2. if a group doesn't have a child then no arrow/image
3. if a group with child expanded then show up_arrow (^)

To achieve something similar to this:

1. Your `ExpandableListView` will look something similar to this with `android:groupIndicator` null

   ```
    <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
   ```
2. Your group/header layout will look something like this with text and image at the end:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivDrawerHeaderItemIcon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_30"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_30"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:src="@drawable/switch" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_condensed_regular"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_15"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_15"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10" />
```

3. In your `BaseExpandableListAdapter`'s `getGroupView()` method, use

   ```
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))).size() > 0) {
        if (isExpanded) {
            ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
        } else {
            ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
        }
    }
   ```

Where, `expandableListTitle` is group and `expandableListDetail` is its children

Answer (score 1):

Just Create a view/Imageview where ever u want in the xml of group item example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_group"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/group_icon_not_expanded" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_thin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

And then for your ExpandableListView use a GroupClickListener to change the image for ImageView programmatically, example :

```
listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

            if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_icon);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_icon_not_expanded));
            } else {
                ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.expandable_icon);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_icon_expanded));
            }
            return false    ;
        }
    });
```