# ExpandableListView expanded view not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-drawable

I have an ExpandableListView that I want to customize with a different view when the item is expanded.  The problem is the image I have assigned to the state_expanded attribute is never shown.  I've tried almost all other attribute for the state but the only one that does anything is state_pressed and it just briefly shows a different image when the state is pressed.  How do I get my list_item_expanded drawable to stay shown when the item is expanded?  Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Here is my selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_expanded" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item"></item>
</selector>
```

Here is my where I style my ExpandableListView

```
<style name="customExpandableList" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:groupIndicator">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:childDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I set the selector as a drawable in the adapter like so:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trans_sum_row, null);
    }
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_item_selector));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do what I was trying to do.  The `android:state_expanded` attribute is only applicable to the group indicator and not the ExpandableListView itself.  What I ended up doing was creating one selector for the ELV and another for the group indicator like so

```
<style name="customExpandableList" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
  <item name="android:groupIndicator">@drawable/custom_group_selector</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_elv_selector</item>
  <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:childDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

After that I was able to get the same effect I wanted by positioning the group indicator where I wanted by using the SO solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501413/change-expandable-indicator-in-expandablelistview)

Positioning the group indicator this way hasn't proven the best solution for me because I'm seeing different results on some phones but that is a different post in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue, I needed something reliable doing exactly what I expected of the state_expanded flag (and optionally the state_last flag for items), eg expand the background of the group to its children.

I ended-up doing something like this allowing me to reuse that for all ExpandableListView:

The idea is to derive from this adapter class and implement the 2 abstract method it defines (instead of the originals). Then you'll have to create the 4 backgrounds for each state (I personally used shapes but I'm sure 9-patches will do very well here too).

The group_padding is used to make sure the group view is not on top of the left indicator.

```
public abstract class ccc71_expandable_list_adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
protected Context context;
private int group_padding;

protected abstract View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, View convertView);

protected abstract View getGroupView(int groupPosition, View convertView, View parent);

public ccc71_expandable_list_adapter(Context ctx)
{
    super();

    context = ctx.getApplicationContext();

    TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft });

    group_padding = (int) ta.getDimension(0, 10f);

    ta.recycle();
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = getGroupView(groupPosition, convertView, parent);

    if (isExpanded)
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_shadow_expanded);
    }
    else
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_shadow_collapsed);
    }
    v.setPadding(group_padding, v.getPaddingTop(), v.getPaddingRight(), v.getPaddingBottom());

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, convertView);

    if (isLastChild)
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_shadow_child_last);
    }
    else
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_shadow_childs);
    }

    return v;
}
}
```