# Alignment of Android Expandable list view group indicator

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to change Exapandable listview group indicator. So I have tried like below:

```
<ExpandableListView 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"      
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandablelist_selector"/>
```

expandablelist_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
android:drawable="@drawable/minus"
android:state_expanded="true" ></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/plus"></item>
</selector>
```

I have used 9 patch images. But the indicator is coming in top not in center. Please help me how to center group indicator icon/image.

[Edit]

Below is the dummy image reference:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=o5oxkx&s=5#.UqAcb9IW13N

Comment: Did you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15518717/1665507 ?

Comment: @SpringBreaker In above link, they are aligning group indicator onto right side. I want group indicator to be in the center.

Comment: I want group indicator vertically center on left side

Comment: Post a dummy image of what you want.It will be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: @SpringBreaker I dont have that many reputations to upload image. Please suggest me is there any other way to post dummy image

Comment: You can upload the image in any free image hosting site and post the link here.

Comment: @SpringBreaker I have posted the dummy image link.