# How to set group indicator in extendable listview

Tags: android

I have group indication with small icon, and i use groupIndicator to call the layer_list to draw it but I see android by default stretch that icon to fits the text size.

Comment: Check this post in stackoverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501413/change-expandable-indicator-in-expandablelistview