# Expandable listview with indicator image

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview, indicator

I have a customized expandable listview.
Now I want a arrow on the left side of every group.
I tried it like that (note the section "`getGroupView`"):

```
 package com.aaron.waller.mrpolitik.tabs;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.aaron.waller.mrpolitik.R;

    /**
     * Created by Oclemmy on 5/10/2016 for ProgrammingWizards Channel and http://www.Camposha.com.
     */
    public class FragenFragment extends Fragment {
        View rootView;
        ExpandableListView lv;
        private String[] groups;
        private String[][] children;
        public ImageView groupholder;



        public FragenFragment() {

        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            groups = new String[]{"Ich habe einen Eiswürfel verschluckt und ihn noch nicht ausgekackt, steckt er fest?",
                    "Warum macht meine Katze komische Geräusche wenn ich micht auf sie stelle?", "Wird mein Laptop schwerer, wenn ich mehr Dateien draflade?",
                    "Warum vibriert meine Katze?",
                    "Platzhalterfrage","" +
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage",
                    "Platzhalterfrage"};

            children = new String[][]{
                    {"s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."},
                    {"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of comes from a line in section 1.10.32."},
                    {"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)."},
                    {"There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc."},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},
                    {"Platzhalterantwort"},

            };
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragen_layout, container, false);

            return rootView;

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            lv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
            lv.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(groups, children));
            lv.setGroupIndicator(null);
            groupholder = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupHolder);

    /*        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((MainActivity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;

            lv.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));

    */

        }

      /*  public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
            // Get the screen's density scale
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
            return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
        } */

        public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

            private final LayoutInflater inf;
            private String[] groups;
            private String[][] children;

            public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
                this.groups = groups;
                this.children = children;
                inf = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return groups.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return children[groupPosition].length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return groups[groupPosition];
            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);


                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }



                holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;





               if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupHolder1);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


                }

                    if (isExpanded) {
                        groupholder.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow1);
                    } else {
                        groupholder.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
                    }

                }



                holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

                return convertView;



            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }

            private class ViewHolder {
                TextView text;
            }



        }

    }
```

But I dont know where to put these lines:

```
if (isExpanded) {
            groupholder.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow1);
        } else {
            groupholder.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
        }
```

At the moment the app crashes if I try to open the Fragment with the expandable listview.

This is my expandable listview:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/expListView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

And this is my list_group.xml where I customized the group design:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/groupHolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupHolder1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="#282828"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:ignore="SpUsage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my group_indicator.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow1"
        android:state_expanded="true" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow2" />

</selector>
```

How do I have to rewrite the code that it works?
I'm new to Android Studio.

Comment: lv.setGroupIndicator(null); no need add in Java too . If you give XML it's enough

Comment: Then have you created a drawable.xml. to show image when selected.

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS Watch my edited answer. The last section "group_indicator.xml"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501413/change-expandable-indicator-in-expandablelistview. Refer this for clarification.....